# How to enable the readonly input

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have an input box using ng Ant design now am using the readonly attribute for the input field. once the user click on edit the readonly has to become the editable field. how to achieve this.

Code:

```html
<i nz-icon type="edit" class="toolbar-icon" (click)="edit()"></i>
<input type="text" nz-input [ngModel]="'French'" [readonly]="true">
```

ts file:

```js
edit() {
   console.log("function called");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<input [readonly]="{{ variable }}>".`

In your `*.component.ts`, initialize the variable:

```
private variable: boolean = true;
```

**Edit 1**

So this up is not working you need to

In your `*.component.ts`, initialize the variable:

```
  @Input() editable: boolean = false;
    edit() {
     console.log("function called");
     this.editable = true;
    }
```

And then you can use for example

```
<button (click)="edit()">Click me!</button>
<input type="text" [readonly]="!editable">
```

Sorry for first bad answer.
Live demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bei96r

Comment: Did you put in edit function => this.variable = true ?

Comment: core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{ variable }}] in .  <input [ERROR ->][readonly]="{{ variable }}">

Comment: @lakshmipriya i update answer, sorry for didn't try before i say answer, i forgot that's this first answer don't do job :)

Comment: thank you but its throwing this error.  Cannot find name 'Input'.

Comment: import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
:)

Comment: thank you it is working but the cursor is not blinking on the input field when we click on the edit

Comment: Ok my friend, i was away from my comp :) You need to add #input (for example change that name that's like a reference like a id for our input ) and add   @ViewChild("input") input: ElementRef; in your *.component.ts . Then same add in our function this.input.nativeElement.focus();  You can all see this in our demo :)

Answer (score 0):

The square are used to bind to a variable. And I don't think `true` is a variable in your ts file.

You can however pass `true` as a string.

```
<input type="text" nz-input [ngModel]="'French'" [readonly]="'true'">
```

Or remove the square brackets totally

```
<input type="text" nz-input [ngModel]="'French'" readonly="true">
```